# Por que "segmentation fault " quando se intercala dois arrays?

Tags: c, c++

Estou construindo um simples programa em c/c++ que intercala dois *arrays* mas estou encontrando um erro inconveniente. Creio que ao chamar a função `IntercalarArranjos`, o programa apresenta um erro do tipo "segmentation fault".

Não sei se errei na lógica dessa função e sei que esse problema está relacionado a acesso indevido da memória ou simplesmente *overflow* da mesma. Perdoem me, mais sou ainda iniciante nesse assunto.

Aqui está o código:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 /****
 *
 *   Título do módulo :
 *
 *   Descrição geral  :
 *
 *   Entrada :
 *
 *   Saída   :
 *
 ****/
 void IntercalarArranjos ( float * primeiroArranjo , float *  segundoArranjo , float * arranjoIntercalado ,int quantPrimeiroArranjo ,  int quantSegundoArranjo , int quantArranjoIntercalado ){

     int i , j , k ;

     k = 0;

     j = 0;

     i = 0;

     while ( i < quantArranjoIntercalado ){

         if( j > quantPrimeiroArranjo ){

             *( arranjoIntercalado + i ) = *( segundoArranjo + j );

             k = k + 1;


         }

         if( k > quantSegundoArranjo ){

             *( arranjoIntercalado + i ) = *( primeiroArranjo + k );

             j = j + 1 ;

         }

         if(  j <=  quantPrimeiroArranjo && k <= quantSegundoArranjo ){

             if( i % 2 == 0 ){

                 *( arranjoIntercalado + i ) = *( primeiroArranjo + j );

                 j = j + 1 ;

             }
             else {

                 *( arranjoIntercalado + i ) = *( segundoArranjo + k );

                 k = k + 1 ;

             }
         }

     }
 }

 int cont = 0 ; /** variável global **/

 /****
 *
 *   Título do módulo : ImprimaVetor
 *
 *   Descrição geral  : Imprime o arranjo desejado
 *
 *   Entrada : (int) quantidade de elementos , (float) vetor dos elementos
 *
 *   Saída   : nenhuma
 *
 ****/

 void ImprimaVetor( int quantVetor , float * realVector ){

     int i ;

     cont += 1 ;

     if( cont == 1 ){

          printf("\nPrimeiro arranjo : ");

     }

     else{

         if( cont == 2 ){

             printf("Segundo arranjo : ");

         }

         else printf("Arranjos intercalados : ");

     }


     for( i = 0 ; i < quantVetor ; i ++ ){
         printf(" %f ", *( realVector + i ) );

     }

     printf("\n\n");

 }


 /****
 *
 *   Título do módulo : LeiaVetor
 *
 *   Descrição geral  : Lê o vetor de elementos
 *
 *   Entrada : (int) quntidade de elementos do vetor , (float) vetor dos    elementos
 *
 *   Saída   : nenhuma
 *
 ****/

 void LeiaVetor( int quantVetor , float * realVetor ){

     int i ;

     for( i = 0 ; i < quantVetor ; i ++ ){

         printf("\n\nDigite o %d elemento do arranjo :", i + 1 );
         scanf("%f", realVetor + i );

     }

 }

 int main()
 {

     float * primeiroArranjo , * segundoArranjo , * arranjoIntercalado ;
     int quantPrimeiroArranjo , quantSegundoArranjo , quantArranjoIntercalado ;

     printf( "---------------------------------------------------------");
     printf( "\nInsira a quntidade de elementos do primeiro arranjo :" );
     scanf("%d", &quantPrimeiroArranjo );

     primeiroArranjo = (float*) malloc( quantPrimeiroArranjo*sizeof(float) );

     LeiaVetor( quantPrimeiroArranjo , primeiroArranjo );

     printf("\n\n");

     printf( "---------------------------------------------------------");
     printf( "\nInsira a quntidade de elementos do segundo arranjo :" );
     scanf("%d", &quantSegundoArranjo );

     segundoArranjo = (float*) malloc( quantSegundoArranjo*sizeof(float) );

     LeiaVetor( quantSegundoArranjo , segundoArranjo );

     printf("\n\n");


     printf( "---------------------------------------------------------");

     quantArranjoIntercalado = quantSegundoArranjo + quantPrimeiroArranjo ;

     arranjoIntercalado = (float*) malloc(  quantArranjoIntercalado*sizeof(float) );

     IntercalarArranjos ( primeiroArranjo ,segundoArranjo ,arranjoIntercalado ,quantPrimeiroArranjo , quantSegundoArranjo ,quantArranjoIntercalado );

     ImprimaVetor( quantPrimeiroArranjo , primeiroArranjo  );

     ImprimaVetor( quantSegundoArranjo , segundoArranjo  );

     ImprimaVetor( quantArranjoIntercalado , arranjoIntercalado );

     printf("\n\n");

     return 0 ;

 }
```

Comment: C/C++ não existe! Se pretendes usar C++, usa C++ (`new`, `delete`, etc ... não uses `malloc()`, `free()`, etc)

Comment: Desculpe. Mas não achei seu comentário construtivo. E sim , posso usar malloc() e free() em um programa c++ . O que me impede ? Mas não é esse o problema.

Comment: *Hint*: uma forma mais usual de escrever `*(apontador + deslocamento)` é `apontador[deslocamento]`.

Answer (score 3):

As instruções

```
     k += k + 1;
     j += j + 1;
```

deviam ser

```
     k = k + 1;
     j = j + 1;
```

ou

```
     k += 1;
     j += 1;
```

ou

```
     k++;
     j++;
```

Comment: Valeu. Nem percebi esse "detalhe" . Mas o problema persiste ainda.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Caro colega, analisando o seu código percebi que ao alterar o operador relacional de **<** como consta no seu código, para **>**, dentro da função **IntercalarArranjos()** ele não exibe **segmentation fault**, mais precisamente nessa parte citada abaixo:

```
while ( i > quantArranjoIntercalado )
```

o que pude perceber é que você "instruiu" que enquanto i for menor que **quantArranjoIntercalado** faça isso, mas não houve uma verificação, visto que a única instrução que alterei foi essa além de declarar as funções antes de definilas.

Obs:Outra coisa que pude perceber no seu código é você está alocando, mas não se preocupou em liberar o que foi alocado.